# Parse XML for the data I want with nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri gem to parse a XML data, but having problem in obtaining the data I want selectively.

Here is my controller code:

```
      def matches

      f = File.open("england.xml")
      doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)

      @away =  doc.xpath("//league/match/odds/type[@name='1x2']/bookmaker[@id='821']")
      @homeaway = doc.xpath("//league/match/odds/type[@name='Home/Away']/bookmaker[@id='781']")
      @overunder = doc.xpath("//league/match/odds/type[@name='Over/Under']/bookmaker[@id='781']")
      @handicap = doc.xpath("//league/match/odds/type[@name='Handicap']/bookmaker[@id='781']")
```

This is a part of the XML feed that I have problem:

```
  <league>
   <match>
    <odds>
     <type name="Handicap">
      <bookmaker id="781" name="Bet365">
       <handicap name="-1.75">
        <odd name="1" value="2.15">
       </handicap>
       <handicap name="+1.75">
        <odd name="2" value="1.68">
       </handicap>
       <handicap name="-1.50">
        <odd name="1" value="1.95">
       </handicap>
       <handicap name="+1.50">
        <odd name="2" value="1.95">
       </handicap>
      </bookmaker>
     </type>
     </odds>
    </match>
   </league>
```

This is my view:

```
 <table id="tableID">
   <td>Home
    <td>Away</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </td>
   <% @handicap.each do |k| %>
   <tr>
   <td><%= k.parent.parent.parent.children.attr("name") %></td>
   <td><%= k.parent.parent.parent.children[1].attr("name") %></td>
   <td><%= k.children[2].attr("name") %> | <%=          k.children[2].children.attr("value") %></td>
   <td> <%= k.children[3].attr("name") %> | <%= k.children[3].children.attr("value") %></td>
   </tr>
   <% end %>
   </table>
```

Assuming there are quite a few of handicap, I would like to always show the handicap odd value which is closest to 2.00, how can I do that? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: XML parsers can't tell you which value is closest to another value. They *can* extract values that are in the XML, and you can write code to determine which of those are closest to your target value. As is, your sample code doesn't match your XML.

Comment: @theTinMan I think it can be done in XPath 2.0, but good luck finding a parser that supports it!

Comment: We can probably find one in the future. We'll know some day.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will extract values from your XML. You'll have to figure out how to determine which entry in the array is closest to your target:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<league>
 <match>
  <odds>
   <type name="Handicap">
    <bookmaker id="781" name="Bet365">
     <handicap name="-1.75">
      <odd name="1" value="2.15">
     </handicap>
     <handicap name="+1.75">
      <odd name="2" value="1.68">
     </handicap>
     <handicap name="-1.50">
      <odd name="1" value="1.95">
     </handicap>
     <handicap name="+1.50">
      <odd name="2" value="1.95">
     </handicap>
    </bookmaker>
   </type>
   </odds>
  </match>
</league>
EOT

handicap_odd = doc.search('type bookmaker[id="781"] handicap').map{ |handicap| 
  odd = handicap.at('odd')
  [
    handicap['name'], 
    odd['name'], 
    odd['value'].to_f
  ] 
}
```

After running, `handicap_odd` contains an array of `handicap` names and the associated `odd` values:

```
handicap_odd
# => [["-1.75", "1", 2.15],
#     ["+1.75", "2", 1.68],
#     ["-1.50", "1", 1.95],
#     ["+1.50", "2", 1.95]]
```

You'll need to figure out what `search` and `at` do and why they're different.

Notice that I use CSS instead of XPath for the selector, which is for readability.